# Addin dockable in Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise-architect

I'm developing an Add-in in C# for Enterprise Architect, when user selects a menu item then a WPF GUI will pop-up.

How can I make this WPF GUI to dock (using docking) on Enterprise Architect GUI? Can I make the add-in GUI dockable?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `Repository.AddTab()` or `Repository.AddWindow()` depending if you want your window to show up in the main diagram part, or as a regular docked window

From the [manual:](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/add-ins___scripting/repository3.html)

> **AddTab (string TabName, string ControlID)**
>
> activeX custom control
>
> Notes: Adds an ActiveX custom control as a tabbed window. Enterprise
> Architect creates a control and, if successful, returns its Unknown
> pointer, which can be used by the caller to manipulate the control.
>
> Parameters:
>
> TabName: String - used as the tab caption ControlID: String - the
> ProgID of the control; for example, "CS_AddinFramework.UserControl1"
>
> **AddWindow (string WindowName, string ControlID)**
>
> Notes: Adds an ActiveX custom control as a window to the Add-Ins
> docked window. Enterprise Architect creates a control and, if
> successful, returns its Unknown pointer, which can be used by the
> caller to manipulate the control.
>
> Parameters:
>
> WindowName: String - used as the window title ControlID: String - the
> ProgID of the control; for example, "CS_AddinFramework.UserControl1"

You might need to wrap your WPF window into a Winforms Control in order to allow EA to create it as an ActiveX control.

This is an example of an add-in I wrote: the [EA Navigator](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Toolpack/tree/master/EANavigator)

[image]

Comment: Now I'm using code below and I want to add this view in Add-Ins Tab from EA:             if (_testWindowViewModel == null) _testWindowViewModel = new TestWindowViewModel(repository);
            _mainWindow = new TestView(_testWindowViewModel);
            _mainWindow.Show();

Comment: First I will transform Window in UserControl (XAML), this user control is bind with a viewModel in behind TestView(_testWindowViewModel).  But still can not Add this user control to Add-Ins tab like you have in image above. I tool also the project share by you, but are missing projects like  EAAddinFramework and others

Comment: You have to make sure to register your control in COM. All the other required repositories are available in the same github.

Comment: yes I registered the control in COM and the Addin is in EA, but still for Window and Tab is not working. I attached an example of code with 3 options: pop-up window (working), window that should be in Addin tab (not working) and tab window (not working). I'm using WPF with MVVM. GIT: https://github.com/IcePeak89/EA_Addin.git

Comment: EA expects an ActiveX control registered in COM. I think you'll need to wrap your WPF into a winforms control to get this working.